# adjective for commissioned salesperson behavior

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

What's the most descriptive adjective available for the way a salesperson acts when they are paid on commission? "Pushy", "smarmy", "self-centered", and "disingenuous" all come to mind, but none of them really paints the whole picture. Would anyone care to suggest a candidate?

Obligatory example sentence:

> "I found the interaction off-putting because of the persitistently and
>   unmistakably ________ behavior of this stranger towards me, despite
>   this being a social occasion"

Comment: aggressive?  But not all commissioned salespersons are unpleasant.

Comment: You are looking for a single word which means, basically, "unpleasantly commissioned-salespersonlike". You'll have to coin one, I suppose. But I don't know why you would. Languages let you use multiple adjectives for a reason, and this is it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mercenary, as an adjective, means "working or acting merely for money or other reward; venal" according to thesaurus.com. That could work. ("Venal" does not work, though.)

I'd prefer a word that just means "commercial" and would fit in your sentence better than "commercial" does.

Answer (score 1):

Slang but effective: **sales-ey** = heavy-handed chumminess that is self-serving for the sole purpose of making a sale; pushy with an agenda

> "... from the moment he walked into my office, he was insincere and **sales-ey**. He spent the whole time boasting about how great his paper was. After a few minutes, it was obvious that all he cared about was making a sale. He never made an effort to learn about my business. I couldn’t get rid of him fast enough.”

[National Newspaper Association, May 3, 2013, by John Foust](http://www.nnaweb.org/article?articleId=558)

Answer (score 1):

For the example sentence, ***salesmanlike*** may work.

> "I found the interaction off-putting because of the persitistently and
>   unmistakably ***salesmanlike*** behavior of this stranger towards me,
>   despite this being a social occasion"

Wiktionary:

> *Adjective*
>   **salesmanlike** (comparative more salesmanlike, superlative most salesmanlike)
>
> **Resembling or characteristic of a salesman.**